# How do I display java.lang.* object allocations in Eclipse profiler?

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling

Using the Eclipse profiler, I am interested in number of allocated instances of classes from java.lang (for instance `String`). I also want to know stuff like number of calls to `String.equals()` etc.

I use the "Object Allocations" tab and I shows all classes in my application and a count, but there is **no mention of any standard java classes.**

For instance, this silly code shows up in the Object Allocations tab as `1000 Foo`, `7 byte[]`, `4 char[]` and `2 int[]`. Nothing else.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Object obj[] = new Object[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        new Foo();  // Some custom class
        obj[i] = new StringBuffer("foo" + i);
    }
    System.out.println (obj[30]);
}
```

It seems the profiler simply ignores everything that is in any of the java.* packages. The same applies to Execution Statistics as well.

Do I need to enable instrumentation for the core java classes or is there some setting I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same Eclipse profiler listed [here](http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/index_profiler.html) you need to set the inclusion/exclusion filters up.  In your case, you can add a particular package or class to the inclusion filter, or simply remove it from the exclusion filter pre-defined.  I would go with the former as its the more conservative approach and will most likely have a lower impact  on your application performance.  Removing something from the exclusion filter may result it removing more than you intended or wanted, meaning that more code is instrumented.

Comment: Ah yes, I found it! For the record, the setting is in Profile Configuration/Monitor. Then select "Java Profiling - JRE 1.5 or newer" in the tree and click "Edit Options".